# Jquery Mobile Datebox on Simple Modal Dialog Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having problems trying to put a jquery mobile datebox on top of a jquery mobile simple dialog modal (a custom HTML one). I am wondering if this is even possible and if so does anybody has a possible solution. So far all I can get to work is the "inline" date picker (this means that it is static on the modal and doesn't pop up.) Thanks!

Here is my code (the date pick box option I am trying to accomplish):

```
//calls modal
$('#addDialog').live('vclick', function() {
    $(this).simpledialog({
        'mode' : 'blank',
        'prompt': false,
        'forceInput': false,
        'fullHTML' : "<label for='mydate'>Date</label>" +
        "<input name='mydate' id='mydate' type='date' data-role='datebox'data-options='{\"mode\": \"calbox\", \"noButtonFocusMode\": true}'>"
```

Comment: What version of jQM and DateBox? Are there no examples here: http://dev.jtsage.com/#/jQM-DateBox/ or Here: http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/

Comment: I am using the latest versions on both of these. Although, there are examples of how to preform these events separately, I don't see an example of how to do both together (meaning: a datebox with a pop up ontop of a modal dialog)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/206649/j-t-sage will probably answer but will try to get a working demo soon for you

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: It's quite possible that the custom modal window hides the popup, although it does normally appear below it

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the issue might be that the datebox popup appear at a lower z-index than your custom modal window. If such is the case, set it in datebox's input data-options attribute. For example:

```
data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useDialogForceFalse":true, "zindex":10000}'
```